# How to get code files from TFS databases backup

Tags: tfs

I have backup of TFS databases and I want to get my code files from it. Is it possible? If so, then what exactly do I need to do? TFS Version: 11.0.61030.0 (Tfs2012.Update4)

Whatever investigation I have done so far, it seems that the only way to restore the files is to install TFS 2012 on another machine, restore the database backups on that machine. And hopefully afterwards I should be able to download the files from this new TFS. I wanted to verify my procedure because I need to know if there is something missing in my understanding before I start the task.

Comment: If what you have is a backup of TFS, then it seems that the way to recover it would be to restore to TFS.  That restored instance should have everything that was backed up and should be accessible like any other TFS instance.  Your question implies that you already know this though, so it's not clear what you're asking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes restore is the way to go, but you must be careful at some important details. I write as I remember:

1. Use the same version of TFS for the new environment.
2. The new environment is in the same Active Directory domain. If you are in a workgroup, must add additional steps to make, at least some, accounts match.
3. Restore from a marked transaction (this is done by the built-in backup/restore tool)
4. You will have two live system with the same identifier: this may confuse clients. To avoid run the `tfsconfig ChangeServerID` command.
5. If you restore the Configuration DB, must run `TfsConfig RegisterDB`.
6. For getting code this is enough, but consider that the new environment is still pointing to existing resources: build server, lab management.
7. If the TFS instance was already used, more steps are necessaries, like cleaning cache on AT.

I do not remeber a complete guidance: there are many variations on this topic. Make sure to study the content of [Restore a deployment to new hardware](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh529826.aspx)